# Editing text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to edit and update some text in React. I'm trying to use a prompt for this but I'm not sure if that is correct. Nothing is showing up when I console.log `this.state.newText`. Is there a better way to go about updating the text? I'm using tables in my HTML so using inputs in it causes an error. Thanks!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {IndexLink} from 'react-router';
import Item from '../styles/LinkItem.css';

class LinkItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0,
      text: this.props.link,
      newText: '',
      editing: false
    };
  }
}
editLink() {
  var newText = prompt('Update your link');
  this.setState({
    newText: newText,
    editing: false
  });
  console.log(this.state.newText);
}
handleClick() {
  const clicks = this.state.clicks;
  this.setState({
    clicks: clicks + 1
  });
  localStorage.setItem(`link-${this.props.link}`, JSON.stringify(clicks));
}
render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <IndexLink onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} to={{pathname: 'landing/' + this.props.link}}>{this.props.link}</IndexLink>
        </td>
        <td>{JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`link-${this.props.link}`))}</td>
        <td><button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.editLink.bind(this)}>Edit</button></td>
        <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.props.data.deleteLink.bind(null, this.props.index)}>Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
  );
 }
}

export default LinkItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is async. Use a callback (a function that executes after the `state` is set) for `console.log`. That is the correct way. `setState` allows a callback. Right now it's printing nothing as it's printing the old value of `newText` which was set to the empty string in the constructor.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

```
this.setState({
    newText: newText,
    editing: false
  },function(){
     console.log(this.state.newText);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the value of state after updating it, you need to mention it inside the `setState callback` because `setState` takes some time to mutate the state and since javascript is async your `console.log()` gets executed even before the state is mutated. This is what the [setState docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) mention

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

Use the below code

```
editLink() {
    var newText = prompt('Update your link');
      this.setState({
        newText: newText,
        editing: false
      }, function(){
        console.log(this.state.newText);
    });
}
```